# Capture image from firewire video cam in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, camera, webrtc, firewire

Can i capture the source video from a camera connected to the firewire port using MediaStream api on google chrome browser? Or is possible only for camera connected on usb?

Comment: I don't actually know the answer to this :), but what happens when you run getUserMedia with your camera attached via FireWire, for example with http://www.simpl.info/gum? If this doesn't work (but the simpl.info/gum example works OK with your built in or USB webcam), please file a bug at http://new.crbug.com.